# Error - No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have seen multiple questions for the same issue. I went through all the answers and tried all of them. I updated pip, tensorflow, python etc to the latest versions or as suggested in the answers and still I am facing this issue.

Pip version 18.0,
Python 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please downgrade Python to 3.6.x and try again. I had faced similar issue while using Python 3.7.x. Once I downgraded it, it worked. Make sure you adjust your path variable accordingly. "Pip" also may have to be modified and the corresponding path variable.